# How to check values of a variables and functions in solidity like javascript via console.log

Tags: solidity

How to check values of a variables and functions in solidity like javascript  via console.log? Because i need visibility of results for deep understanding.
I am newbie...

i tried hardhat but need more understand.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie too, but I know this (I think)!
There is no console in solidity, you need to write a function for this, or just put it public in the variable itself!

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Value {
    uint public num; //add "public" to see the value

    function add(uint _num) external{
        num += _num;
    }

    //this function is for returning value
    function viewNum() public view returns(uint){
        return(num);
    }
}
```

Also use the Remix editor, it's in the browser. There are plenty of videos on the internet!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hardhat, then you can use `console.sol`.
You need to import it into your contract.

```
import "hardhat/console.sol";
```

Now, you are able to log your variable while you are working.

```
console.log(__your_variable__);
```

If you are still looking to log your variables once you deploy your contract, then you need to use `event` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Import hardhat console:

```
import "hardhat/console.sol";
```

Use console log in your contract

```
console.log(variable); //Variable value
console.log(1234); //direct value
```